# Jquery focus on specific input elements using switch statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

**What I'm trying to do**

When user press enter, I wish to focus on those input elements which data-index attribute value between 0-2 also there type is text and check their attribute values using switch statement to do specific actions.

Below is my design code:

```
<div id="formelements" class="panel-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd" >Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-index="0">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-index="1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-index="2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Below is my jquery code which I am trying:

```
$('#formelements').on('keydown', 'input', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $('input[type=text]').each(function () {
                switch ($(this).attr('data-index')) {
                    case '0':
                        $(this).focus();
                        break;

                    case '1':
                        $(this).focus();
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        $(this).focus();
                        break;
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current implementation would always put focus on the last input field since you are iterating through every input field and then set the focus on the one which has data-attr.

If you want to focus to the next input after you click enter , you would only need to the target the next occurring element with data-index++.

```
 <div id="formelements" class="panel-body">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd" >ENTER WOULD NOT WORK ON THIS FIELD:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd" >Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-index="0">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-index="1">
  </div>
        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd" >ENTER WOULD SKIP THIS FIELD:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-index="2">
  </div>
</div>

    $('#formelements').on('keydown', 'input', function (e) {          
        if (e.which == 13 && $(this).attr("data-index")) 
        {   
            var cur = $(this).attr("data-index");
            $('input[data-index]').each(function ()
            {
                var ele = $(this).attr("data-index");
                if(ele == cur)
                {
                    ele++;               
                    $("input[data-index='" + ele + "']").focus();
                    return false;
                }
            });        
           e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/742r7t6f/1/

Comment: Appreciate your effort but In above question I also mention specific action perform which means when user focus on data-index="2" form will submit automatically. So how can I achieve this goal?

Comment: You may check the value of ele in the code and if it is equal to 2, just do $('form').submit();

Answer (score 0):

This will not work, instead of that use find the data index with value index zero and target the element... Becasue in ur code the reference to this will be lost.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // cannot use .children() because the <dt> are not direct children
    $('#formelements').find('.form-control').each(function() {
        alert("what ever u want to target");
        //and ur code 
    });
})
```